# Passing variables to By.CSS_SELECTOR, getting InvalidSelectorException Python

Tags: python, css

I'm trying to pass variables to a Functiion and insert them into a Find_element(By.CSS_Selector...) statement. When the data is hard coded the statement works, when I insert a variable it fails.

This statement works:

```
Def makeTee()
   driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rwdTr:nth-child(65) select").click()
```

When I attempt to pass a variable to the Function and insert it into the same statement CSS_SELECT it fails with InvalidSelectorException.

```
Def makeTee(teeTime)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rwdTr:nth-child(teeTime) select").click() 

teeIndex = 65
makeTee(teeIndex)
```

I've tried using format in a really simple substitution example but still no luck.

```
Def makeTee()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rwdTr:nth-child({}) select").format(65).click() 

makeTee()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since find_element is expecting a string as the second parameter, your .format should be applied to the string, not the return of find_element.

e.g. `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rwdTr:nth-child({}) select".format(65)).click()`

Comment: :) remember to mark it as the answer to help the next person who comes along